# Selecting the times from json using jquery

Tags: jquery, json

Can someone please help me. I would just like to get the times based on the date selected from this json using jQuery.
so from dropdown I select '12-10-2013' I then want to display the times in a div. Not that difficult I guess.

```
["11-10-2013",{
               "time":["6:30 PM","6:00 PM","5:30 PM","5:00 PM"]
},
"12-10-2013",{
               "time":["10:00 PM","9:30 PM","9:00 PM"]
}]
```

Many many thanks in advance

Comment: `$("#dropdownID").on("change",function(){ $("#time_div").html( $(this).val() ); });` where you have the time as the value in your dropdown and the date as the label...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had to change the format of your array...

http://jsfiddle.net/Na5ua/

```
<select id="dropdown"></select><br/><br/>
<div id="times"></div>

var info = {
    "11-10-2013" : { "time" : ["6:30 PM","6:00 PM","5:30 PM","5:00 PM"] },    
    "12-10-2013" : { "time" : ["10:00 PM","9:30 PM","9:00 PM"] } };

var selectHtml = ""; 
$.each( info, function( date, times ) {  
    selectHtml += '<option value="' + times.time + '">' + date + '</option>';
});

$("#dropdown").html( selectHtml);

$("#dropdown").on("change",function(){
    $("#times").html($(this).val()); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an **array** not JSON. The times in this case are

`array[1].time`

and

`array[3].time`

Notice the times are in an array as well, so an array will be returned by both of these...